# Phone disconnects from USB after 5 seconds on Windows

Tags: usb, charging, motorola-moto-g

My phone recently underwent continued exposure to water (in my pocket during a heavy storm), and after drying it out, I have a problem with its USB port:

- When connecting the phone to a *Windows* computer, it indicates charging, is detected as a device by the system, but it is not possible to browse its files. **But** after approximately 5 seconds, it is completely ejected and stops charging.
- When connecting to a *Linux* or *Mac* computer, it works flawlessly, charging and able to transfer files.

I suspected it could be some sort of short causing an overload and the motherboard shutting down the port, but does not seem to be the case, since when monitoring the current (with an app in the phone, and an USB volt+amp-meter it looks to be well within range of the expected values.

After ruling out overload, I thought that maybe the data bus could be damaged, but upon testing on a Linux, a Mac and another Windows, it worked perfectly, even transmitting big files to check if it would fail at some point succeeded. Seems this is an exclusively Windows-related problem.

It could be the cable, but after testing with a different one, the same behaviour was observed (works on Mac/Linux,  disconnects on Windows).

Any ideas how to fix this? It's a bit annoying since I usually use my Windows machine to charge the phone.

Comment: Is the behaviour same on all ISB ports of windows machine? Asking to rule out problem with a particular port

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, same behaviour with all USB ports, on both Windows machines.

Comment: time to change the USB cable

Comment: @SagarV Forgot to add this info: same behaviour with 2 different USB cables, which work with other phones or when connecting to non-Windows.